# getting nuget package restore to run in go continuous delivery

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-mvc-5, webdeploy, nuget-package-restore, thoughtworks-go

we have a solution with a mvc5 application, and i am trying to use thoughtworks go continuous delivery system to checkout, compile and use webdeploy to publish the web site.

at the moment i have an msbuild task in a job to do all of this, however the nuget package restore part fails.

i do not want to commit the actual packages to our source control, i want nuget to do its job and go to do its.

the error log in go shows the following:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Go
>   Agent\pipelines\Target-Web.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073:
>   The command ""...nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Go
>   Agent\pipelines\Target-Web\MyProject.Web\packages.config"
>   -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "..\ "" exited with code 1. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Go
>   Agent\pipelines\Target-Web\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj]

when i log on to the go server and the go agent as the account that go runs as i can run the msbuild command from the given location as expected.

this is the task that go is trying to run

```
[go] Start to execute task: <exec command="%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe" >
<arg>MyProject\MyProject.csproj</arg>
<arg>/p:DeployOnBuild=true</arg>
<arg>/p:PublishProfile=UAT1</arg>
<arg>/m</arg>
</exec>
```

Comment: so having read this blog post http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html, and the corresponding docs page on NuGet i have changed my solution configuration. Now i am stuck at the 'WARNING: Unable to connect to the remote server' message. I have tried setting the proxy settings, clearing the proxy settings. I have tried turning verbosity on for more details, ive tried running fiddler - still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured that the go agent was running a local service and this account didn't seem to have relevant privileges. once i changed the account to run with more elevated rights the issue was resolved.

Comment: Another possible cause for this error is the proxy for the account that's running the TFS build service. In order to fix that situation, log in as the build service account and set up the proxy there. This was my problem with connecting to NuGet, and it took a while to figure out.

Comment: @JimRoth you are right, this seems to be an issue people suffer as well, we looked in to it while trying to solve our issue. Indeed it may well have helped smooth the path to our eventual solution - but its certainly worth flagging for other users